# React input states not updating after the form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When uploading the form with react the states aren't getting updated like they update for a second then go back to the inputted values I don't know why is this happening

[Gif showing the code behaivour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW17J.gif)

### These are the states

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    // Single File upload hooks
    singleFile: {},
    selectSingleFile: false,
    singleTitle: '',
    singleArtist: '',
    open: false,

    // Multiple File upload hooks
    multipleFiles: [],
    selectMultipleFiles: false,
    multipleTitle: '',
    multipleArtist: '',

    uploadStatus: Number,
  });
```

### This is the handleSubmit code

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // converting into the form object
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', values.singleTitle);
    formData.append('artist', values.singleArtist);
    formData.append('file', values.singleFile);

    // making request to the server
    let reqOptions = {
      url: '/music/singleFile',
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData,
    };
    axios.request(reqOptions).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      setValues({ ...values, uploadStatus: response.status });
    });

    // Setting the hook back to default values
    setValues({
      ...values,
      singleFile: {},
      selectSingleFile: false,
      singleTitle: '',
      singleArtist: '',
      open: true,
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

### [Form Code](https://pastebin.com/sZMtLvm5)

Comment: The state is clearing before the api call has taken place. You should clear your state in a .then rather than at the end/

Comment: yea understood from your solution thanks for it 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    // converting into the form object
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', values.singleTitle);
    formData.append('artist', values.singleArtist);
    formData.append('file', values.singleFile);

    // making request to the server
    let reqOptions = {
      url: '/music/singleFile',
      method: 'POST',
      data: formData,
    };
    axios.request(reqOptions).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      setValues({ ...values, uploadStatus: response.status });
    }).then(res =>{        
    // Setting the hook back to default values
    setValues({
      ...values,
      singleFile: {},
      selectSingleFile: false,
      singleTitle: '',
      singleArtist: '',
      open: true,
    });
     });

    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

Place your state clear in a .then so then you know for sure it will only clear after the api call was succesful.

Comment: thank you very much for the solution it solved it, was quite a silly mistake but as I couldn't figure it out was a bit frustrated so asked a question